# generate object from array of numbers where value will be random color

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array of number

```
const array = [
  51, 53, null, 68, 89,
  64, 80, 43,   87, 49,
  73, 75, 81,   88, 90,
  6,  50, 47
]
```

I need to gerenerate a random color for each number I want to get an object like

```
const colors = {
51 : "green",
53: "red",
// and so on
}
```

Color could be rgb or any that I can use as background-color
And colors should be uniq. I tryed to make a cicle and create for every number a color, but I don't now how to make it uniq

Comment: Are these all the numbers? or will there be more numbers?

Comment: ok, so what issue are facing while working on this logic?

Comment: _"I tryied to find lib which will help me"_ - And now we should do the job? Did you try anything to solve this on your own (other than searching for a library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate random hex char (0-9 a-f) with:

```js
(Math.random()*0xF<<0).toString(16)
```

You can iterate to generate 6:

```js
function random_color() {
    let color = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += (Math.random()*0xF<<0).toString(16);
    }
    return '#' + color;
}

console.log(random_color()); // --> "#8e69ef"
```

Then you can easily associate a color for each number.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function randomToColorObj(arr){
        const rand = ()=>Math.round(255 * Math.random()*1);
        return arr.filter(item=>item !== null).map(item=>{
            return {[item]:[rand(),rand(),rand()]};
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. How does this answer the part of the question that asks that colors be unique?